# AdBlock rule for blocking facebook.com outside the facebook.com domain

Tags: facebook, adblock

from: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3035418

So I wrote some filter rules in my filter file, than I uploaded it to my domain, it looks like this:

```
[Adblock Plus 1.1]
||facebook.com^$domain=~facebook.com|~facebook.net|~fbcdn.com|~fbcdn.net
||facebook.net^$domain=~facebook.com|~facebook.net|~fbcdn.com|~fbcdn.net
||fbcdn.com^$domain=~facebook.com|~facebook.net|~fbcdn.com|~fbcdn.net
||fbcdn.net^$domain=~facebook.com|~facebook.net|~fbcdn.com|~fbcdn.net
```

and I added it to the Adblock Plus as a filter. I can see these rules in the filters options, etc.

But it doesn't work!: [sorry for giving the url of the example site]:

http://9gag.com/gag/308206

So under the idiot pictures there is a "facebook comment" part - and it's not blocked with these rules.

**Q**: How can I block facebook.com (and facebook.net, etc. ) outside the facebook.com domain? I don't want to facebook trace that what sites am i visiting (the first URL in this post, the ycombinator).

Comment: Use the Ghostery addon. It blocks Facebook, and anything else *you* want. http://www.ghostery.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
[Adblock Plus 1.1]
||facebook.com$domain=~www.facebook.com
||facebook.net$domain=~www.facebook.com
||fbcdn.net$domain=~www.facebook.com
```